# Рассказ и новелла

Tags: литература

Специалисты, подскажите, пожалуйста, чем рассказ отличается от новеллы? И почему новелла так называется (явно связано со словом "новый")?
Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рассказ и новелла относятся к малым формам эпической прозы.

Рассказ - это повествовательное произведение, которому присущ небольшой объем, малое количество героев и кратковременность изображаемых событий. Этот вид эпического жанра восходит к фольклорным жанрам устного пересказа, к иносказаниям и притчам.

Как образец литературного жанра, новелла возникла в эпоху Возрождения - самым знаменитым примером является "Декамерон" Бокаччо.  Новелла чаще всего раскрывает проблему через одно событие. От рассказа новелла отличается  острым сюжетом, строгостью композиции, художественной сжатостью. . Расцветом новеллы считается период романтизма. Со временем новелла стала изображать парадоксальные и необычные происшествия, определяющие судьбу человека.

Слово «новелла» заимствовано из итал. языка  в начале 18 века, novella –  суф. производное от nova – «новый». Изменение значения слова происходило следующим образом: «новости» →«повествование новостей →«повесть-новелла».

Что же нового в новелле?  Она всегда  открывает новое в известном. Это может быть новое (необычайное) происшествие в спокойном течении жизни,  или герой выходит из столкновения с проблемами обновленным, пережившим духовным кризис, или нам открывается новый взгляд на повседневную действительность. Недаром  расцвет новеллистического жанра всегда совпадает с переломными эпохами: сначала Возрождение, потом романтизм и, наконец,  новелла XX в как результат кризиса реализма.

Answer (score 2):

Рассказ = новелла.
Русский термин против международного. Есть ли прямое сходство? Рассказ - известие, услышанное от непосредственного очевидца или пересказчика. Новелла - "новость" (novella, nouvelle), краткая история "из первых или вторых рук". Сходство налицо, различия носят чисто субъективный характер. Русскому *рассказу* приписывают больше психологизма, что недоказуемо или зависит от творческой манеры конкретного автора; иностранная *новелла* скорее сюжетно-информативна, чем перегружена размышлизмами. Обратные примеры легко находятся, поэтому вопрос не принципиален. Малая проза, *не публицистика*, то есть без широких общественных обобщений, без морализаторства, спокойное авторское восприятие/впечатление.